# Do limit and skip operations become stateless when unordered

Tags: java, java-stream, stateless, stateful

My question is quite simple. The intermediate limit and skip operations on java streams are lablled as being stateful operations - I assume because they by default need to limit or skip the first n elements on an ordered stream.

If I make the input source stream unordered by invoking the unordered() method or using an unordered source, can we effectively say that these operations could then be considered stateless, or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `limit` and `skip` are still stateful operations as the processing of elements depends on information about the processing of other elements (i.e. whether they have been processed).

These operations are easier to implement for unordered stream, but this doesn’t change their stateful nature.

You can tell this by simply asking youself: “can this operation get implemented for a single element by just looking at the element and nothing else (besides unchanging information known prior to starting the entire stream operation)?”

Comment: Ah yes, I suppose a filter, can carry out its filtering without any care for any other elements, whereas, limit, needs to know how many other elements have already been processed?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that your question is regarding parallel streams as in current Stream API implementation sequential streams don't use ordering in any way.

Current parallel unordered `skip/limit` implementation uses buffer of size 128 for each parallel task, so it's possible that you will read more elements from the source than actually necessary. This is done to reduce the possible contention on a shared atomic variable which might be crucial for low-Q tasks (tasks where per-element processing is quite fast). So to answer your question, no, unordered `skip/limit` operations are still stateful.

You may easily check this with the following program:

```
AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();
IntStream.range(0, 1_000_000).parallel().unordered().filter(x -> true)
        .peek(x -> counter.incrementAndGet()).limit(1000).toArray();
System.out.println(counter.get());
```

It prints how many elements were actually taken from the source. On my four-core system this code prints usually 1280 (128*10) or 1408 (128*11), even though 1000 elements were requested.

Comment: I think, this is focusing too much on implementation details. And the question whether a stream might process more elements than necessary, isn’t relevant to the question whether the operation is stateful.

Comment: @Holger, I agree, but it depends on what actually OP wants to know.

Comment: @TagirValeev I'm a little confused by your statement of: "in current Stream API implementation sequential streams don't use ordering in any way". What about operations such as findFirst() and findAny() - do they behave exactly the same when not run in parallel? Also what about something like distinct() - would this not retain an ordering if one existed, but not need to if the source was unordered, even when ran sequentially?

Comment: @Tranquility, yes, sequential `findFirst()` and `findAny()` are the same. Also `forEach` and `forEachOrdered`. And `distinct()` does not take any advantages on unordered stream in sequential mode (though preserving order for `distinct()` seems to have no overhead).